# jQuery Datepicker Calendar - Allowing only 1 day in calendar based on previous dropdown form value

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create a webform that allows a user to select entries from multiple drop down boxes for a party booking.

In summary, i need the user to be able to choose a day for their party, which then gives them options in terms of different times for their booking based on what day is chosen etc.

The first dropdown box allows them to choose one of the available days, either: Tuesday, Friday, Saturday or Sunday. then the next lists all the available dates for the given day.

The last input in in the form is a jQuery datepicker calendar which should only allow them to choose any day in the future but only the chosen day from the previous drop down box. ie for example if they chose Saturday from dropdown box 1, then only Saturdays should appear in the calendar

So far i have got the dependent drop down boxes working but i cant seem to work out how to pass the value from the dropdown list to the datepicker calendar.

I am aware of the function beforeShowDay, but am not sure how to use a variable from the previous form input rather than a static assignment of excluded dates in the code.

if anyone has any advice on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sample which will illustrate

[How to restrict date selection to specific week days in the dropdown?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-restrict-date-selection-to-specifc-week-days-in-the-dropdown/)